# How to implement search on utf encoded data

Tags: mysql

In my table I have data in my column(title) like the following

> à®µà®´à®•à¯                                                                                                                          à®¤à®²à¯                                             |                                                                          à| à®•à®Ÿà®¤à¯³à®°à¯

How can I implement search on this column:

```
select title from blog where title like '%stackoverflow%',
```

Comment: When your data looks like that you first need to work on getting the character set settings right. After that, a normal `SELECT` should just work.

Comment: That is not "utf encoded data", that's [*garbage*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). Because you have mistreated the encoding somewhere on the way to insert it into the database.